# Mounting samba share from fstab

Tags: linux, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

Currently I have 3 network drives I mount each time i restart my system. The command I use is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.8/ARES /media/Ares -o user=USER,password=***
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.8/ATHENA /media/Athena -o user=USER,password=***
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.8/PLUTO /media/Pluto -o user=USER,password=***
```

I would love to add these puppies over to fstab so I did some googling and came up with this gem: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-a-system-to-automount-a-samba-share-with-etcfstab/  the issue is my system refuses to see smbfs as a valid type, and boot fails. What is the correct way to mount samba shares via fstab as cifs?

I had tried:

```
//192.168.1.8/PLUTO /media/Pluto      cifs   username=USER,password=** 0 0
```

but this also resulted in a failed boot.

***EDIT***

I guess i could put them all in a bash script, and run the bash script on system boot....but that seems like a crappy work around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a wiki page which deals in [details about Samba mount](http://www.berthon.eu/wiki/foss:wikishelf:smb:cifs), either using the smbfs or cifs file system type.

I do not see any error in what you tried. <strike>Perhaps you could try to use `smbfs` instead of `cifs`, take care that the options might be slightly different!</strike> `smbfs` is the deprecated SMB filesystem in the Kernel, it is still here around for historical reason. You should keep on using `cifs` which is the supported filesystem.

In addition, I recommend to use the `credentials` option, so you can put the password in a safer place than `fstab` which is often world readable!

Finally, you do not need to reboot to test your `/etc/fstab` changes. Simply umount your share (if it is mounted) and mount it again by typing:

```
mount /media/PLUTO
```

Comment: ** "world" readable, not "word" readable... some people just might get confused...

Comment: @kalaracey thanks for spotting the typo, this is now corrected.